# Android - Updating JSONObject with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm having trouble updating JSONObject.

Basically, I have user who has username and password, and I put them on my server using JSONObject and Volley.

Here is my code of putting JSONObject into server:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.putOpt("username", username);
    jsonObject.putOpt("password", password);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject resp) {
            // Response handling
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        // Error handling
    });
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Now, I'm trying to **change the password** that I passed into JSONObject but I have no idea where to start from.

Can someone give me a guidance?

Comment: What did you mean by changing the password? Do you want to change the password after you've made the volley request? Then you might consider making another volley request by creating another `JsonObject`.

Comment: Yes, I want to change the password after I have made the volley request.

Comment: I tried making another volley request, but it gave me 400 error.

Comment: You can not change the password in the middle of a volley request. You can change the password and then again make another volley request if you want.

Comment: `I tried making another volley request, but it gave me 400 error` - Yes, it should if its an API for signing up. So the user already exists in the system and you're getting a bad request exception.

Comment: Then should I remove the user and then make another volley request?

Comment: Yes you might consider that as well.

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks and glad to know that helped.